# Smarty / PHP does not show error why it's not rendering anymore

Tags: php, smarty

this is a little bit hard to explain so feel free to ask for further details.

Scenario: I built a website using smarty as template engine. Alle the texts I use are located in my lang.php file. I now wanted to to exactly the same as before (in a first step), but reading the "language array" from the databse.

But as soon as i call my TextReading function smarty does not render anything anymore, even though i DO NOT override the existing texts.

Looks like this:

```
$content = new Content("en");
$result = $content->getTexts();
// ONLY CALLING, NOT CHANGING ANYTHING
// var_dump($result) ==> WORKING!
$lang_en = array ( ... );
$lang_de = array ( ... );
```

The function getTexts is working perfectly. I can dump the results, or i can leave the table empty - nothing changes, the code stops working suddenly. The actual language variables ($lang_en, $lang_de) or not yet affected by my call.

I also tried to activate my log:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Nothing seems to help.

Any Ideas?

UPDATE: So the problem is calling the datbase. If I do not call it - it is working (for example just by returning "test" before the actual call). The Problem is: The call is working - I can return the results, but smarty isn't rendering ....

UPDATE2 (db call):

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT NAME, CONTENT FROM content_text WHERE LANG='DE'")) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $lang);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

...
```

But as said - the call is working. I do retreive a result (the table content) but smarty stops rendering...

Comment: will you show us also the code that is triggering the not-displayed error please?

Comment: i somehow managed to find the problem: I still do not know why, but smarty tried to include the lang.php file more than once. By this it also tried to redeclare the defined classes - there it failed. I curretnly solved it by using require_once instead of require until i find out why it is loading more than once